# Actualizar atributo de un modelo con signals en Django

Tags: python, django, signals

Estoy tratando de cambiar el atributo del modelo producto "estado_prestamo" pero cuando se crea un nuevo registro en el modelo devolucion. Como los modelos no estan relacionados directamente aun no entiendo como crear el query para llegar desde Devolcion hasta Producto.
Estos son los modelos que tengo.

```
class Producto(ClaseModelo):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    modelo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    estado_prestamo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marca, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    imagen = models.ImageField(upload_to='producto/', null=True, blank=True)
 
   
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}:{}'.format(self.categoria.descripcion, self.marca.descripcion)
 

 
class Prestamo(ClaseModelo):
    prestamo_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    fechaPrestamo = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    trabajador = models.ForeignKey(Trabajador, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}:{}:{}'.format(self.trabajador,self.producto,self.prestamo_id)
 
class Devolucion(ClaseModelo):
    devolucion_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    fecha_devolucion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    prestamo = models.ForeignKey(Prestamo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    observacion = models.CharField(max_length=100)
 
 
    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.devolucion_id)

@receiver(post_save, sender=Devolucion)
def actualizar_prestamo(sender, instance, **kwargs):
   
    id_prestamo = instance.prestamo.id
 
    pre = Prestamo.objects.filter(pk=id_prestamo).first()
 
    if pre:
        pre.estado=False
        pre.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu señal tendría que ser así:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Devolucion)
def actualizar_prestamo(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.prestamo.producto.estado_prestamo = True # Puedes ser True o False
    instance.prestamo.producto.save()
```

Una **devolucion** se relaciona con un **prestamo** que a su ves se relaciona con un **producto**.

Por otra parte aquí:

> ```
> id_prestamo = instance.prestamo.id
>
> pre = Prestamo.objects.filter(pk=id_prestamo).first()
>
> if pre:
>     pre.estado=False
>     pre.save()
> ```
>
> Estas actualizando una instancia del modelo `Prestamo` y tu dijiste
> que querías actualizar la instancia del modelo `Producto`... ademas de
> que el modelo `Prestamo` no tiene un campo `estado`, lo cual dará
> error.

---

Espero haberte ayudado.